# I can't preview data in SSIS 2017

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to extract data from an Oracle DB to SQL Server with SSIS 2016.

I installed a Windows Server 2016, a SQL Server 2016 and a SSIS, a Visual Studio Professional 2017 and the ODTwithODAC122011 from Oracle for the drivers.

Searching for a solution I find this question:
[Error while extracting data from Oracle DB in SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49974824/error-while-extracting-data-from-oracle-db-in-ssis)

I try to set Run64bitRuntime as false but doesn't work for me and still get the following error:

> The system cannot find message text for message number 0x80040e51 in
>   the message file for OraOLEDB. (OraOLEDB)

In the following images I  show the value for Run64bitRuntime variable and the error message.

[image: Run64bitRuntime value]

[image: Error Message]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?