# SSIS Stucks on populating destination tables

Tags: oracle, ssis, oledbconnection

When I am connecting my localdb instance of oracle sql developer in SSIS visual studio 2015, the test succeeds but when I select the Name of the table or the view dropdown , it stucks on "Loading....". Please see the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Do you know how many tables are in `XE.system`?

Comment: @tgolisch Its 129 for system user..

Comment: Can anyone please resolve my issue, the deadline is tight and I am not able to figure out the solution..

Comment: @MukeshTiwari You tried to query your data by picking 'SQL Command' from Data access mode menu?

Comment: @Ozan Sen
I have tried using that as well . The syntax I am able to parse , but when I click on "View Existing Data" it throws below  error:

There was an error displaying the preview.

The system cannot find message text for message number 0x80040e51 in the message file for OraOLEDB. (OraOLEDB)

Comment: Please check this ,especially look at the comments section: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49974824/error-while-extracting-data-from-oracle-db-in-ssis

Comment: @Ozan Sen Yes I read this article  but the execution  is still giving me the below error :
Error at Data Flow Task [OLE DB Destination [796]]: Columns "zcdistrcode" and "ZCDISTRCODE" cannot convert between unicode and non-unicode string data types.

Comment: @MukeshTiwari, Excellent. This is a simple error to solve. You have 2 options. Either you need to change destination table column datatype from VARCHAR() to NVARCHAR() or vice versa. As 2nd option, you need to do it at Oracle Source Part. Right Click, select advanced editor, go to output columns and change data types in the same way in the first option. You need to ensure uniformity. Both source and destination column (zcdistrcode - ZCDISTRCODE) data types should be unicode or non-unicode.